# "for whom" or "for who" (in the following sentence)

Tags: relative-clauses, relative-pronouns, free-relative-clauses

What's correct in the next sentence, "for whom" or "for who"

**"This site is also for whom English is not his mother tongue."**

The options are:

> 1. This site is also for **whom** English is not his mother tongue.
> 2. This site is also for **who** English is not his mother tongue.

Comment: something tells me that it should be ***This site is also for those whose mother tongue is not English.***

Answer (score 1):

Relative clauses usually refer to nouns,pronouns,determiners,etc. Here you can say " The site is also (meant) for people/for those " and then choose the clause. As "English "is a noun here I would say "whose English isn't their mother tongue".

Comment: There can be different relative clauses with the same meaning. Just consider "The site is also for people studying English as a foreign /second language. For non-natives studying English."